# Increase column width of command line

Tags: linux, ksh

When I type commands on command line I see symbol **<** after typing 75 charachters.

```
/developer/home/aravind.sreeram> klklkjlkjljlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj                   <
```

I've tried `stty cols 200` but did not work, can someone please tell me how can I see full command beyond 75 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `resize` command. It should increase the column size of the terminal.

Comment: Thank you, this command helped me see how number of COLUMNS and rows exported, I've changed and it worked well. Just a question when I do `resize` I see number of `LINES=63`, what does `LINES` represent here?

Comment: @Aravind  LINES represent rows

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to happen automatically you can add the following to your .kshrc :

```
# set to unsigned short int and autoexport
typeset -usi -x COLUMNS
builtin stty
# update term width
_utw()
{
        unset COLUMNS c
        typeset -usi c=${ stty cols; }
        (( COLUMNS= 12 + c ))
        return
}
# the WINCH signal is sent when the terminal window size changes
trap '_utw' WINCH
_utw
```

I add 12 to the number of columns stty reports (using the builtin saves us spawning a process) because the `<` at the end of the line was farther from the edge of the terminal than I wanted. You may have to adjust this number depending on the font you're using.